# Resharper thinks that typecast is redundant, but without typecast the code does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, casting, resharper, litjson

Iterating [JsonData](https://github.com/lbv/litjson/blob/master/src/LitJson/JsonData.cs) through foreach fetches `IDictionary` enumerator instead of `IList` one.

```
foreach (var jsonEntry in jsonData)
```

This causes my code to throw an error.

```
InvalidOperationException: Instance of JsonData is not a dictionary
LitJson.JsonData.EnsureDictionary ()
LitJson.JsonData.System.Collections.Specialized.IOrderedDictionary.GetEnumerator ()
LitJson.JsonData.System.Collections.IDictionary.GetEnumerator ()
```

Casting the object to `IList` causes Resharper to issue a warning *"Type cast is redundant."*

```
foreach (var jsonEntry in jsonData as IList)
```

Why does Resharper think the cast is redundant ?

Comment: Damn, I really don't like the two externally implemented `GetEnumerator()` methods in that class.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does Resharper think the cast is redundant ?

If you think this way:

IList is a ICollection and IDictionary is also a ICollection because both of them implement 'ICollection', Resharper's warning should become clear.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to see that casting to `IList` forces `foreach` to call another `GetEnumerator()` implementation. Can't really blame JetBrains because it looks like a very rare case.